# Impala does not return right data

Tags: impala

I have 2 Impala queries:

```
select * from table_1  
where  
  id ='5f4d3f626d248400285ccd35' or 
  id ='5f50f94f6d248400225cdd5c' or 
  id = '5f51ca0b6d248400285cde9e' or 
  id = '5f4f69b5f66ee63f149ea9cf'
```

it returns only 2 rows.

But if I query:

```
select * from table_1  
where  
  id ='5f4d3f626d248400285ccd35' or 
  id ='5f50f94f6d248400225cdd5c' or 
  id = '5f51ca0b6d248400285cde9e'
```

without `5f51ca0b6d248400285cde9e` item, it return 3 rows.

I expect the first query to return 4 rows.

What happens with my query?

Comment: something is wrong with the way you are firing sql or the sql client is acting up. Are you using impala shell or hue?

Comment: I used Impala shell to query

Comment: This is very strange, you can try below solution but its not really a solution. I am curious if this is happening for other data sets or not?

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting try this alternative query which might point to a bug in the `OR` clause or if you might just have data issues.

```
select * from table_1 where id in 
 ('5f4d3f626d248400285ccd35','5f50f94f6d248400225cdd5c',
'5f51ca0b6d248400285cde9e','5f4f69b5f66ee63f149ea9cf')
```

Comment: Let me try your solution.